# getting combination of indices of on bits from 2 bitmaps

Tags: c, bitmap, bit-manipulation

This problem has 2 level
Level 1. 
I have a 64 bit bitmap and I know only few of them are on or set to 1. Is there a way to get which bits are set without using branching ?

e.g.___(0)___________________________________________________________(63)

BMP = 000000001000010000000000010000000000000000000000011000000000000

f(BMP) = {9, 14, 26, 51, 52}

Level 2.

Now I have 2 64 bit bitmaps and I need combination of set bits in 2.

e.g.____(0)___________________________________________________________(63)

BMP1 = 000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000011000000000000

BMP2 = 000000000000010000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000

f(BMP1, BMP2) = {(9,14), (9, 26), (51, 14), (51, 26), (52, 14), (52, 26)}

1. I know that the bitmap almost always is sparse.
2. It would be great if the solution suggested can be expanded to more than 2 bitmaps at a time but I would rather have a method which works extremely fast for upto 2 and then a little slower for more than that.
3. Even if solution without branching is not possible then please suggest what will be fastest possible method with branching.

(Sorry for bad formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the possible bitfields in a hash table, if there are only a relative few of them, such as if you know no more than two bits are set and there are at most a few thousand possibilities.

Failing that, there are a few tricks you can do with two’s-complement arithmetic and signed numbers to get the first bit set in a vector. `v & -v` will get you a column vector of the lowest-order bit that’s set in `v`.  You can bitmask and repeat to get them all.